# On click myFunction and wait until it is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this is something easy to do but I dont find anything helping me out of this.

I have a function

```
(function($){
    myFunction = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // do stuff
        // load ajax content
        // animate and show
    }
    $('.button').on( 'click', myFunction);
})(jQuery);
```

now this works but I need to know, wait untill everything is done if someone presses many `.button`s in a short time cause there are a few elements with class `button`

I've tried with promise()

```
$('.button').on( 'click', function(){
    $.when( myFunction() ).done(function() {
        alert('finished')
    });
});
```

but that gives me an error `e is undefined` and

```
$('.button').on( 'click', myFunction).promise().done(function() {
    alert('finisehd');
});
```

anyone knowing what I'm doing wrong and how I could do it to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution would be to set a variable inside the click handler when `myFunction` is called and check its state with every call of the click handler.
This could be done somewhere along the lines of this:

```
(function($){
    var wait = false;

    myFunction = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (wait) {
            return;
        }

        wait = true;

        // ...

        wait = false;
    }
    $('.button').on( 'click', myFunction);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `myFunction` expects one argument, when you call `myFunction()` the argument is missing.
Not tested but it should works:

```
$('.button').on( 'click', function(e){
    $.when( myFunction(e) ).done(function() {
        alert('finished')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not passing in the `e` variable. You're using `$.when` incorrectly.

If you want to have the `done` function called *after* `myFunction` finishes its ajax call. You'll need to return a promise from `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction(e) {
    return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        doAjax(function(content) { // callback
            deferred.resolve(content);
        });
    });
}
```

Now when you do

```
// inside event handler
$.when(myFunction(e)).done(function(content) {
    // whoo!
});
```